# how do i add a int to a string

Tags: c++, string

i have a string and i need to add a number to it i.e a int. like:

```
string number1 = ("dfg");
int number2 = 123;
number1 += number2;
```

this is my code:

```
name = root_enter;             // pull name from another string.
size_t sz;
sz = name.size();              //find the size of the string.

name.resize (sz + 5, account); // add the account number.
cout << name;                  //test the string.
```

this works... somewhat but i only get the "*name*88888" and... i don't know why.
i just need a way to add the value of a int to the end of a string

Comment: "i don't know why". The second parameter to `resize` is a char, and resize uses it repeatedly to fill in any extra space it creates at the end of the string. In your case `account` is equal to 56 (mod 256), so you've passed the character `8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int a = 30;
  stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);

  ss << "hello world";
  ss << '\n';
  ss << a;

  cout << ss.str() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are no in-built operators that do this. You can write your own function, overload an `operator+` for a `string` and an `int`. If you use a custom function, try using a `stringstream`:

```
string addi2str(string const& instr, int v) {
 stringstream s(instr);
 s << v;
 return s.str();
}
```

Comment: "There are no in-built operators that do this." I am disappoint. Oh well, I guess they couldn't think of *everything*...

Answer (score 4):

You can use string streams:

```
template<class T>
std::string to_string(const T& t) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}

// usage:
std::string s("foo");
s.append(to_string(12345));
```

Alternatively you can use utilities like Boosts `lexical_cast()`:

```
s.append(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(12345));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

```
int x = 29;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "My age is: " << x << std::endl;
std::string str = ss.str();
```

Comment: or use ostringstream to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lexecal_cast` from boost, then C `itoa` and of course `stringstream` from STL